# Xcode create clickable text

Tags: xcode, text, hyperlink, clickable

I am trying to create an object that can have clickable text within it.

For instance: I have text displayed to the user:
*"Please verify the terms and conditions prior to accepting registration."*

I want to make just the *"terms and conditions"* text show as a link. The text would be underlined an blue.

When the user clicks the text I want them to be navigated to my terms and conditions viewcontroller page. So the link is internal to the application, not an external web page.

**Questions**

1. How do I display the text with only making the specific text linkable?
2. How do I 'seque' to the ViewController page via the user clicking the linked text?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, you could make the text a custom button and set the text color to blue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel).  From the readme file:

> In addition to supporting rich text, TTTAttributedLabel allows you to automatically detect links for URLs, addresses, phone numbers, and dates, or allow you to embed your own.
>
> ```
> label.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll; // Automatically detect links when the label text is subsequently changed
> label.delegate = self; // Delegate methods are called when the user taps on a link (see `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` protocol)
>
> label.text = @"Fork me on GitHub! (http://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/)"; // Repository URL will be automatically detected and linked
>
> NSRange range = [label.text rangeOfString:@"me"];
> [label addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://github.com/mattt/"] withRange:range]; // Embedding a custom link in a substring
> ```